# Обновление данных при смене языка в Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема с выводом мультиязычного контента из базы. Данные прилетают в таком виде (один из айтемов новости):

```
{
  date: "2017-05-19",
  link: "news-1",
  content: [
    {
      language: "ru",
      title: "Новость 1",
      desc: "Краткое описание новости 1",
    },
    {
      language: "en",
      title: "News 1",
      desc: "Small description for news 1",
    }
  ]
}
```

**news.service.ts**

```
export class NewsService {
  constructor (private _http: Http) {}
  getNews() {
    return this._http.get('/api/news/search')
        .map(res => res.json());
  };
}
```

**news.ts**

```
export class News {
    date: string;
    title: string;
    desc: string;
}
```

**news.component.ts**

```
export class NewsComponent implements OnInit {
    news: News[];
    lang: number;

    constructor (
        private _newsService: NewsService
    ) {};

    getNews(): void {
        this._newsService
            .getNews()
            .subscribe(
                news => this.news = news,
                error => console.log(error),
                () => console.dir('Success')
            )
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.lang = ['ru', 'en'].indexOf(localStorage.getItem('localeId'));
        this.getNews();
    }
}
```

**news.componentn.html**

```
<h3>Newslist</h3>

<ul class="news">
    <li *ngFor="let item of news">
        <div class="news-date">{{ item.date }}</div>
        <div class="news-title">{{ item.content[lang].title }}</div>
        <div class="news-description">{{ item.content[lang].desc }}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Код для смены языка находится в **app.component.ts**:

```
export class AppComponent {
    private langs = ['ru', 'en'];

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
        translate.addLangs(this.langs);
        if(!localStorage.getItem('localeId')) {
            let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
            translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|ru/) ? browserLang : 'ru');

            localStorage.setItem('localeId', browserLang.match(/en|ru/) ? browserLang : 'ru');
        } else {
            translate.setDefaultLang(localStorage.getItem('localeId'));
        }
    }

    changeLang() {
        let other = localStorage.getItem('localeId') == 'en' ? 'ru' : 'en';
        this.translate.use(other);
        localStorage.setItem('localeId', other);
    }
}
```

В принципе, всё работает нормально, новости выводятся, если бы не одно "НО", при изменении языка контент не обновляется. При этом если изменить язык и обновить страницу, язык подгружается из `localStorage` и данные уже на другом языке.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать обновление таких переменных, как `item.content[lang].title`, без перезагрузки страницы?**

Comment: а где код для смены языка?

Comment: @Grundy, добавил код для смены языка, думал этот код не особо нужен, наверное, стоит создать полноценый тыкабельный пример, займусь этим позже

Comment: ну собственно, а с чего должен меняться перевод, если в _changeLang_ никак не меняется _lang_ из `News` от которого и зависит вывод?

Comment: Блин, а ведь действительно, спасибо за помощь, буду думать как это дело глобализировать, наверное, имеет смысл сделать сервис для языка

Comment: Вообще говоря, если ты уже используешь _TranslateService_, зачем делать дополнительно свой велосипед? почему не использовать его везде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде *changeLang* никак не меняется свойство *lang* из компонента *NewsComponent*. Именно поэтому не меняется и view, в котором значения зависят именно от этого свойства.

---

Не совсем понятно зачем делать свой велосипед, если уже используется *TranslateService*. Проще всего использовать его везде

---

В любом случае, у *TranslateService* если [свойство](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#properties)

> `onLangChange`: *EventEmitter* слушающий событие изменения языка.

Можно использовать его в *NewsComponent* и в обработчике события, менять нужно свойство

Например:

```
translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
    this.lang = ['ru', 'en'].indexOf(event.lang);
});
```

Comment: добавил код в `ngOnInit()` в news.component, всё прекрасно работает